# Extract attached file from response

Tags: powershell, content-disposition, powershell-6.0

According to [Whitesource document](https://whitesource.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WD/pages/814612683/HTTP+API+v1.3#HTTPAPIv1.3-InventoryReport), the response headers will have

```
Content-Type = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<product name>.xslx
```

I want to extract that xslx file but, I do not know how. I've tried writing the response in a file but, all I got is is a bunch of binary characters.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -SkipCertificateCheck -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body -Uri "https://app.whitesourcesoftware.com/api/v1.3 | Out-File "abcd.csv"
```

I also tried to convert the response to csv before writing it, but that doesn't work either.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -SkipCertificateCheck -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body -Uri "https://app.whitesourcesoftware.com/api/v1.3 | ConvertTo-CSV | Out-File "abcd.csv"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little digging, I realized that the file is present in the `content` part of the respose. I used `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of `Invoke-RestMethod`. Here's my scripts:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body -Uri $server
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("report.xlsx", $response.content)
```

This will write the attached file to a file named `report.xlsx`.